# How to use jsfiddle in my localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WHzKp/14/.

And this is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example4/colorbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").click(function () { //on clicking the link above
        $(this).colorbox({iframe:true, width:"100%", height:"100%"});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>External Form</h3>
<a href="https://dev88.wufoo.com/forms/ze7xusq0j2tum9/" id="test">Please fill out my form.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here in jsfiddle it works fine what i need, but in my localhost run with my html file it didn't working, Can anyone guide me please, What is my mistake?

Comment: because your localhost hasn't any jQuery installed?

Comment: Add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>` before jQuery is used

Comment: @DannyvanHolten: here no need js right? because, it run in server, i don't know exactly and view source of my html file, it shows js and css.

Comment: @ArunPJohny:I added from your comment it didn't work.

Comment: @user3890317 it should be added before `<script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your html to include jquery as that will run in client browser, below I have used the cdn path to jquery which should load before jquery.colorbox.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example4/colorbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").click(function () { //on clicking the link above
        $(this).colorbox({iframe:true, width:"100%", height:"100%"});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>External Form</h3>
<a href="https://dev88.wufoo.com/forms/ze7xusq0j2tum9/" id="test">Please fill out my form.</a>
</body>
</html>
```